# Is there a language which has a polynomial length certificate but not known to have a polynomial time verifier?

Tags: complexity-theory, np

The question came to my mind while studying the NP definition. Do we know any such languages?

Answer (score 1):

For any instance of a problem, take the instance itself as the certificate. Linear size, verifiable in polynomial time for problems in P, not known for problems in NP.

Answer (score 0):

Every NEXPTIME complete language has a certificate of length 0 that can be checked in time $2^{2^{n^{O(1)}}}$, but does not have polynomial length certificate that can be checked in polynomial time.